# How to transfer data through SSH tunnel in SSIS?

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssis

I am working on a SSIS package.I need to write a data flow task to transfer the data from a MYSQL database to my local database through SSH tunnel.

There is no connection manager available in SSIS to perform the above mentioned task.Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be help you.

by the expect script your problem can be solved

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no usr@$myhost.example.com
#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "my_password\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "my_command1\r"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "my_command2\r"
interact
```